# Is there a way to store BLOB type of data in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

How to store BLOB type of data in TDengine? I have some time-series data with large binary data. Is there a way to store then in TDengine?

Answer (score 0):

As for as I know in TDengine 2.x versions blob types are not supported. I also have the same request for this feature. Let's wait for later 3.x versions to see if the functionality will be supported.